# Specifying the target screen of a lone JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, multiple-monitors

I have an application that uses the `JOptionPane.show*` methods to inform the
user about various conditions before displaying the applications main window.
On a multi screen setup these always show on the first screen. This is usually only
a minor annoyance, but becomes a problem when the 0 screen is off or disconnected.

Normal windows can be placed correctly using the `GraphicsConfiguration` obtained
via `MouseInfo`, but I can't find a way to pass that to `JOptionPane`. I can
not either use the main window to anchor the dialogs, because there is no main
window at that stage of the application startup. Among the possible dialogs is
a warning about obsolete java versions, so displaying the main window before the
errors is not option since the user's java runtime may not even be capable of
displaying the main window.

Is there a way to specify the target screen without reimplementing a major part
of `JOptionPane`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a JDialog out of a JOptionPane, and then display the dialog any location that you desire.

As per the [JOptoinPane API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html):

```
 JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(arguments);
 pane.set.Xxxx(...); // Configure
 JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(parentComponent, title);
 // here set the dialog's location
 dialog.setVisible(true);
```

Edit: Alternatively, you could simply create your own JDialog window de novo as per Andrew's great comment (that now no longer exists?).

Comment: Sorry, after I saw your great answer, I felt the comment was redundant & deleted it.  :P

Comment: I was kind of hoping I could do it without dirty tricks in manual placement, but this works. Thank you! For anyone else needing this: remember to take in a account the offsets of the `GraphicsConfiguration`'s bounds.